# x64 Windows 7 version of GStreamer

Tags: java, video, gstreamer, avi, mkv

Can anyone point me to a build of GStreamer for 64 bit Windows 7? I'm looking for a way to play mkv and avi files in Java and all things point to GStreamer, but they don't build for windows, and [OSSBuild](http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/) doesn't build for x64. I would use Xuggler, but they don't have support for x64 either (http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads/).

If anyone has any other suggestions on other ways to play videos in Java (preferably receiving input from an InputStream), that'd be amazing too.

Comment: x64 target for MSVC requires the Pro version which is not-free, hence you will not see many projects building for it.

Comment: http://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings

Answer (score 1):

You can build GStreamer with mingw64.

The [Fedora Mingw project](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW) provides builds for 32 and x64, the development package is there: http://svn.openftd.org/viewvc/Fedora%20Cross%20Compiler%20Framework/mingw-gstreamer/

Comment: Since my initial answer, the fedora-mingw64 project has been integrated in fedora 17.

Comment: And also the GStreamer SDK: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows